# Dynamic object instantiation in Python

Tags: python, oop, instantiation

I'm having trouble finding out how to dynamically instantiate multiple instances of a class. For example, I'm given a file with an x,y,z and t coordinate on each line. I want to place each line into a class named Droplet that is uniquely identified bu the x,y because the z position and time varies with time. Each Droplet will have a hashtable that maps a time to a z coordinate.

The big picture is that each line of input specifies a location of a water surface at a point in time and I will be animating this in Blender using python.

The part I'm having trouble with that I don't know how many instances of Droplet I will have to instantiate, so I can't do something like

```
drop1 = Droplet(0,0)
drop2 = Droplet(0,1)
... and so on
```

Is there a way for me to automate class instantiation using the unique x,y as an identifier in Python?

Comment: Can't you just use a list?

Comment: I'm hesistant about using lists because the list can get huge depending on how long of a time the water is observed and how many points there are (the resolution). I don't want to have to iterate through the entire list each time Blender needs to render that point.

Comment: You can index a list. Anyway, you I see you chose the list solution :-)

Comment: Well, it's a list of unique x,y coordinates. I will still be using a dict to map t to z within the Droplet. Slightly different because in the one I chose, he puts an xyzt per Droplet instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yea just do it in a loop and put the objects into a list:

```
drops = []
for line in file:
    x, y, z, t = parseFromFile(line)
    drops.append(Droplet(x,y,z,t))
```

or, more Pythonesque:

```
drops = [Droplet(*parseFromFile(line)) for line in file]
```

`*`here takes the (presumbably four) values returned by `parseFromFile` and uses them as four arguments for the `Droplet` instantiation

Comment: So in python, we don't have to provide a name for the class instance?

Comment: Well it's not the name of the _class_, it's the name of the instance created from that class. And no, it's just a value which can get assigned to a named variable as in your example, or just put into a list. It doesn't differ from, say, a number value. You can put 1000 numbers into a list and wouldn't think to give them individual names either, right? Same here (not a Python-speciality either)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to uniquely identify them by the x and y direction (and, I guess, overwrite them when a new one with the same coordinates comes along), I'd use a 2-dimensional array indexed by x and y, and store the Droplet objects in that collection.  So something like this:

```
droplets[x][y] = Droplet(x,y,z,t)
```

You'll have to read up on how to initialize 2-d arrays; you need to first make sure that droplets has enough room in both the x and y directions for all the droplets to fit in. But this way you can pick out any particular droplet you want by its x and y coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

At a high level

```
drops = []
with open('drop_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y = line.strip().split()
        drops.append(Droplet(x, y))
```

then you can loop over the list of droplets when you need to do something to each of them.

this assumes that your file is in the format

> x y
>
> x1 y1